# Get the id with wp_rewrite rules

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I can't get the id of the next url :
http://www.example.com/json/compact/id/48/

My rewrite code is :

```
private function initHooks()
{

    add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', [$this,'jsonRules'] );
    add_filter( 'query_vars', [$this,'jsonQueryVars'] );
    add_action( 'template_redirect', [$this, 'jsonTemplate'] );
}

public function jsonRules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
        ['json/(.+?)/id/(\d*)' => 'index.php?json=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );
}
public function jsonQueryVars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'json';
    return $query_vars;
}
public function jsonTemplate() {
    echo "<pre style='position:relative;z-index:9999'>";var_dump( get_query_var( 'json' ), get_query_var( 'id' ));echo "</pre>";
}
```

`get_query_var( 'json' )` is returning the desired result but `get_query_var( 'id')` is null

The rewrite rule is `['json/(.+?)/id/(\d*)' => 'index.php?json=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]']`

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess it's an escaping issue, and that the `\d` written in the code is received by the rewrite engine as a simple `d`. Since the token is optional, the match doesn't fail but the second group is left empty. I think `\\d` should work, but if that's not the case you can also try with `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: $query_vars[] = 'id';  return this also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this

```
public function jsonQueryVars( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars[] = 'json';
        $query_vars[] = 'id';
        return $query_vars;
    }
```